# Where to put test files that get created. Ruby directory structure

Tags: ruby

Say I'm writing an integration test that reads in a CSV and outputs a CSV with some changes in the data. Where do I put this test file in a Ruby project? Is there some convention for where temporary files that get created in tests go that eventually get torn down or delete?

Say my project structure is simple:

```
--root
   --app
     --promotions
   --spec
   Gemfile
   Gemfile.lock
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect candidate for `Dir.mktmpdir`.